# LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /location/name.app with error -10810

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, chmod

I'm trying to open application using nodejs (I'd like this process to be workable in cross-platform , MAC/Windows ..etc

here's the code

```
const { exec } = require('child_process')
const fs = require('fs')

// giving the required permissions , not really sure if 777 is the right choice
fs.chmodSync(appPath,777);

exec("open -a " + path , (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(stdout);
            console.log(stderr);
          });
```

console.log(err); // logs this error

> { Error: Command failed: open -a /location.app
>   LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /location.app with error -10810

when executing the same command in terminal (out of node) , it fires the same issue